# python - transform nested dictionary values using mapper dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, dictionary, nested

**I am looking for an elegant pythonic solution**

I have two dictionaries, an input dictionary and one that contains the mapping information - see below. My goal is to convert any value from the input dictionary into the corresponding `mapper` value IF they have the same 'key path' meaning that `input_dico[k1][k2]` is changed to the value `mapper_dico[k1][k2]` and not `mapper_dico[k3][k2]`

```
mapper = {
    'data_labels': {
        'position': {
            'outside_end': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END',
            'inside_end': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.INSIDE_END'
        }
    },
    'category_axis': {
        'major_tick_mark': {
            'None': 'XL_TICK_MARK.NONE',
        },
        'tick_label_position': {
            'None': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.NONE',
            'high': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.HIGH',
            'low': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.LOW',
        },
    },
    'chart': {
        'clustered_column': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED',
        'clustered_bar': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED',
        'stacked_bar': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_STACKED',
    },
}
```

example input dico:

```
{'category_axis': {'format': {'line': {'fill': 'A5300F'}},
                   'has_major_gridlines': False,
                   'major_tick_mark': 'None',
                   'tick_label_position': 'None',
                   'visible': True},
 'chart': 'clustered_column',
 'data_labels': {'font': {'size': 9},
                 'number_format': '#0.0%',
                 'position': 'outside_end'},
 'value_axis': {'has_major_gridlines': False, 'visible': False}}
```

So you see here, that the example `input_dico['data_labels']['position']:'outside_end'`, `input_dico['category_axis']['tick_label_position']:'None'` and `input_dico['chart']:'clustered_column'` all have to be converted!

I currently do it like this which is really clunky and hard to understand so I'm looking for something most likely recursive, short and simple. **I am also open to ditching the whole use-a-dictionary-to-map-values method if someone has a better solution!**

```
def _reformat(display): #display is the input_dico
    """Change certain values to pptx-python classes."""
    for k1, v1 in mapper.items():
        if k1 in display:
            if isinstance(v1, str):
                display[k1] = mapper[k1]
            else:
                for k2, v2 in v1.items():
                    if k2 in display[k1]:
                        for k3 in v2:
                            if k3 == display[k1][k2]:
                                display[k1][k2] = mapper[k1][k2][k3]
    return display
```

Comment: Fix the example: `input_dico['data_labels']['position']['outside_end']`. `input_dico['data_labels']['position']` is a string not a dictionary. Same story with the other 2 entries you mentioned. I would also change all the constants such as `XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END` to strings so it's easier for us to copy paste the code and try it out.

Comment: @Jatimir I am highlighting the strings that need to be converted and the key path that needs to be respected to get to the strings.

Comment: I get it, but it's misleading if you use `[]` to do that, it looks like another key, not the value.

Comment: So just to get some clarity, you have 2 dicts, (input and mapper). You want that any key (including sub keys) if they exist in mapper dict, their values must be replaced to that in the mapper dict at the same access path. Correct?

Comment: @Ludo Have a look at the performance stats from my answer before you actually pick one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reshaped the code into a method that takes in two inputs: `InputDict` and `mapperDict`. It uses recursion to handle the type `dict` since it's at it's code just mapping `dicts` so if it's a `dict` of a `dict` just call itself.

I see you just have used two level mapping but tomorrow when you have more nesting, you don't want your code to break just because you used two level nesting. Instead your code should scale to handle any sort of nesting and it's types. (following the ideology, write once, use plenty of times.)

```
def _map_content(base, to):
    """Recursively maps the values from a mapping dictionary to an input
    dictionary if they have the same key path.

    base: input dictionary
    to: mapping dictionary
    """

    if not isinstance(base, dict):
        return to[base]

    for key in base:
        if key not in to:
            continue
        elif isinstance(to[key], (int, str)):
            base[key] = to[key]
            continue
        elif not isinstance(to[key], dict):
            raise TypeError("I just found some data type that's not a string, int or dict. You might want to handle "
                            "this. Unless you meant for this. Below is what I found: \n" + to[key])

        base[key] = _map_content(base[key], to[key])        

    return base
```

---

**Usage:**

```
updated_input_dict = _map_content(input_dico, mapper)
print(updated_input_dict)
```

---

**Advantages of this code:**

- Scalable code, so today you have 2 nests, but even if you have 100, it won't matter. The code would scale.
- Works for any two `dict` which means you can reuse it for different mappings too
- Follows `PEP8` guidelines.
- Uses recursion to avoid code repetition.
- Raises an error if the type is not handled.
- Avoids unnecessary indentation

---

**Performance:**

```
print('Mine: ', timeit.timeit(stmt=stAditya, number=1000000)) # 5.524377981713729
print('Jatimir:', timeit.timeit(stmt=stTwo, number=1000000)) # 6.971933613624651
print('Kasramvd:', timeit.timeit(stmt=oth, number=1000000)) # 15.090121147017014
```

I hope this helps, if you need anything please use the comments section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since you reshaped it, it is no longer working. It maps all the possible options to the input dict rather than a single one. Could you please take a look? I can't fix it.

Comment: @Ludo can you add in a sample result that is expected? It'll be very quick to see the issue.

Comment: The output in jatimir's answer is the desired result

Comment: @Ludo I've updated my answer it was the most silliest of things. Now it gives the same result and faster too :)

Answer (score 2):

**Code:**

```
from typing import Union, Hashable, Any

def _reformat(parent: Union[dict, Hashable], mapping: dict) -> Union[dict, Any]:
    """Recursive function that transforms only these dictionary values which keys correspond to a `mapping` dict."""
    if isinstance(parent, dict):
        node = {}
        for key, value in parent.items():
            try:
                node[key] = _reformat(value, mapping[key])
            except KeyError:
                node[key] = value
        return node
    else:
        return mapping[parent]
```

**Example:**

```
mapper = {'data_labels': {'position': {'outside_end': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END',
                                       'inside_end': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.INSIDE_END'}},
          'category_axis': {'major_tick_mark': {'None': 'XL_TICK_MARK.NONE'},
                            'tick_label_position': {'None': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.NONE',
                                                    'high': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.HIGH',
                                                    'low': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.LOW'}},
          'chart': {'clustered_column': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED',
                    'clustered_bar': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED',
                    'stacked_bar': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_STACKED'}}

input_dict = {'category_axis': {'format': {'line': {'fill': 'A5300F'}},
                                'has_major_gridlines': False,
                                'major_tick_mark': 'None',
                                'tick_label_position': 'None',
                                'visible': True},
              'chart': 'clustered_column',
              'data_labels': {'font': {'size': 9},
                              'number_format': '#0.0%',
                              'position': 'outside_end'},
              'value_axis': {'has_major_gridlines': False, 'visible': False}}

converted_dict = _reformat(input_dict, mapper)
import pprint
pprint.pprint(converted_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
{'category_axis': {'format': {'line': {'fill': 'A5300F'}},
                   'has_major_gridlines': False,
                   'major_tick_mark': 'XL_TICK_MARK.NONE',
                   'tick_label_position': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.NONE',
                   'visible': True},
 'chart': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED',
 'data_labels': {'font': {'size': 9},
                 'number_format': '#0.0%',
                 'position': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END'},
 'value_axis': {'has_major_gridlines': False, 'visible': False}}
```

Comment: This seems to be the most elegant solution, but has a bug which I cant seem to solve. If you change `category_axis` to: 'category_axis': {'major_tick_mark': {'None': 'XL_TICK_MARK.NONE'},
                            'tick_label_position': {'None': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.NONE',
                                                    'high': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.HIGH',
                                                    'low': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.LOW'},
                           'has_major_gridlines':'ERROR'} You'll see that only the first value of the string error is there

Comment: I could just make single values a list of length 1 and then it would work i.e. `'has_major_gridlines': ['ERROR']`

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't call it a bug. The way you used `'ERROR'` as a value is not consistent with the example. It should be a dictionary that maps possible values of `has_major_gridlines` to some other object (everything except `dict`), for example: `'has_major_gridlines': {'ERROR': 'error message', 'WARNING': 'warning message'}` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive generator to get all the `display`'s keys and then just check if `mapper` provides that path using `reduce()` function. If it does, then you can simply reassign that value to the respective key in `display` dictionary.

```
from functools import reduce


def get_paths(dis, pre=[]):
    for key, value in dis.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            yield from get_paths(value, pre=pre + [key])
        else:
            yield pre + [key]


def _reformat(dis, pre=[]): 
    for keys in get_paths(dis):
        try:
            map_val = reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys, mapper)
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            val = reduce(dict.__getitem__, keys[:-1], dis)
            val[keys[-1]] = map_val
    return dis
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason for which the code cannot be compact, is that all elements in your mapper do not have the same level of nesting. By simply adding a key `type` on your `chart` dictionary, the code becomes almost straigthforward. Here is the modified structure, and the corresponding code:

```
mapper = {
    'data_labels': {
        'position': {
            'outside_end': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END',
            'inside_end': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.INSIDE_END'
        }
    },
    'category_axis': {
        'major_tick_mark': {
            'None': 'XL_TICK_MARK.NONE',
        },
        'tick_label_position': {
            'None': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.NONE',
            'high': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.HIGH',
            'low': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.LOW',
        },
    },
    'chart': {
        'type': {
            'clustered_column': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED',
            'clustered_bar': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_CLUSTERED',
            'stacked_bar': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_STACKED',
        },
    },
}

display = {
    'category_axis': {
        'format': {'line': {'fill': 'A5300F'}},
        'has_major_gridlines': False,
        'major_tick_mark': 'None',
        'tick_label_position': 'None',
        'visible': True},
    'chart': {
        'type': 'clustered_column'},
    'data_labels': {
        'font': {'size': 9},
        'number_format': '#0.0%',
        'position': 'outside_end'},
    'value_axis': {
        'has_major_gridlines': False,
        'visible': False}
}

def reformat(display): #display is the input_dico
    for key1, dic in display.items():
        if key1 not in mapper: continue
        for key2 in dic:
            if key2 not in mapper[key1]: continue
            display[key1][key2] = mapper[key1][key2][dic[key2]]
    return display

print(reformat(display))
```

Output:

```
{'category_axis': {
    'format': {'line': {'fill': 'A5300F'}},
    'has_major_gridlines': False,
    'major_tick_mark': 'XL_TICK_MARK.NONE',
    'tick_label_position': 'XL_TICK_LABEL_POSITION.NONE',
    'visible': True},
 'chart': {
    'type': 'XL_CHART_TYPE.COLUMN_CLUSTERED'},
 'data_labels': {
    'font': {'size': 9},
    'number_format': '#0.0%',
    'position': 'XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END'},
    'value_axis': {
         'has_major_gridlines': False,
         'visible': False}
}
```

Note: I've replaced your constants by strings to get a self-containing code that can be copy-pasted

Comment: That works only for "2 levels of nesting", since I can see only 2 for loops and the `reformat` function isn't recursive, am I right?

Comment: @Jatimir: You are right, but as the structure is intended for formating, I don't believe that you ever need more that two levels of nesting. A full recursive solution seems to be a little bit overkill here.

Comment: @sciroccorics the example is a simplified version of the dictionaries I'll be dealing with. Most will have varying levels of nesting going from 1-5...

Comment: @Ludo: OK but your OP explicitely mentioned two nesting levels, because you talked about a "key path" composed of two keys, so I adapted my answer to that particular case. If you need to deal with arbitrary nesting, I think that the most elegant solution is the one proposed by Jatimir.